# Read Excel from asset folder.. modify the data and download it angular 4

Tags: angular, angular6

I have requirement where I will be having an pre-defined excel sheet, which I need to read through angular code which will be in asset folder, few columns need to be updated and the file should be downloaded. I have tried various different codes, but still unable to do it. Modules used are xlsx and FileSaver.

Sample Code

```
this.http.get('../../../assets/test.xlsx')
    .subscribe(
    data => {

        const array = new Uint8Array(data.arrayBuffer());
        let arr = new Array();
        for(let i = 0; i !== array.length; ++i) {
            arr[i] = String.fromCharCode(data[i]);
        } 
        let bstr = arr.join("");
        console.log('bstr', arr)
        const wb: WorkBook =  read(bstr, {type:"binary"});
        XLSX.writeFile(wb,'amex.xlsx')
        let first_sheet_name = wb.SheetNames[0];
        let worksheet = wb.Sheets[first_sheet_name];
        console.log(XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet, {raw: true}));
        console.log(data);
    }
```

This is a messy code!!! Thanks in advance

Comment: So what's the non-working part?

Comment: Nothing is working out there. Actually the response data is need to be converted to array and should be given to workbook which I am unable to do. I guess I am doing wrong. I need a full code which some one can help me out